# build a graph with smallest diameter, N verteces, each vertex has degree $\ge k$

Tags: graph-theory

I need to build a graph with number of vertexes N such that each vertex has degree at least k and the graph has the smallest diameter. I believe that this question should be well studied.

EDIT: yes complete graph is an answer, but not interesting. I am changing the question a little bit: each vertex has degree k.

Comment: This is almost a good question.  The problem is that it appears you have put almost no effort into the question yourself.  May I suggest including (a) necessary conditions on the existence of k-regular n-vertex graphs (b) resolving the 1-regular, 2-regular, (n-1)-regular and n-regular cases.  Note, that PhD theses are written about the [degree-diameter problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_diameter_problem), and this is not far off -- it might be difficult to answer this question just for 3-regular (cubic) graphs.

Answer (score 1):

The [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on $N$ vertices, $K_N$, will be hard to beat.  If $k \gt N-1$ are you allowed multiple edges between a given pair of vertices?  I hope so.

Comment: well, k  < N - 1